# Vim settings file on Windows

Tags: vim, windows-7

I can't believe I am typing a question for a simple thing like this but here we are. I can't for the life of me figure out what the exact name for the settings file is for vim on Windows (`.vimrc` does not work on Windows). And if I have names right (read the next para) then I don't know why it is not picking up the settings from it.

I tried creating `_vimrc` and `_gvimrc` in the root directory where I copied the file from the  example settings file that came installed with vim. I set the following command on top of the example commands:

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set guifont=Courier_New:h11:cANSI
```

It is not accepting this file (whether it is named `_vimrc` or `_gvimrc`, I tried both) as the settings file as the font has not changed on the next start-up and still writes backup files.

Comment: Wherever your `%HOMEPATH%` environment variable expands to

Comment: http://www.davidcraddock.net/2010/01/10/config-files-for-the-windows-version-of-vim/ has some  useful pointers.  In particular to invoke `vim -V` to see the actual paths loaded.

Comment: On a stock installation, `:edit $MYVIMRC` should _Just Work_

Comment: @sehe This answer -- `:edit $MYVIMRC` -- has been invaluable. When you're used to Linux after a decade and need to do work on a Windows system, this command just hits the spot.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

my `_vimrc`/`_gvimrc` is stored at `C:/Users/<ME>/_vimrc` and is working fine.

It's generally a good idea to keep personal settings separate from installation files.

To get more information about the search paths for your configuration files, type [`:he vimrc-intro`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#vimrc-intro).

And be careful: the docs say

> For MS-DOS and MS-Windows you can use one of these:
> $HOME/_vimrc
> $VIM/_vimrc

While this is absolutely true, it could be a bit surprising that `$VIM` does not expand to e.g. `C:/Program Files/vim/<your_version>` (this is what `$VIMRUNTIME` holds) but only to `C:/Program Files/vim/`.

This said, `C:/Program Files/vim/_vimrc` should be read during startup.

Comment: argh! of course! I was going with the instructions in the sample file where it says "for MS-DOS and Win32: $VIM\_gvimrc" and I assumed that meant the root folder. Thanks.

Comment: Thought that too until I typed `:echo $VIM`

Comment: How do I figure out what $HOME or $VIM or any $VAR expands to? I tried doing `echo $HOME` and it didn't expand it.

Comment: @Ungeheuer did you try it inside Vim, e.g. `:echo $VIM`?

Comment: @eckes no. I was trying it from command prompt. I'm trying to get into using Windows more for coding, rather than running off to into Linux to do productive things, so I'm stumbling around like a drunkard.

Comment: `$VIMRUNTIME` may point to a location inside `C:\Program Files (x86)` on newer Windows (e.g. Windows 10).

Answer (score 35):

Why not just edit the vimrc file in vim itself and figure it out its name?. Using the following command.

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

As ghiscoding mentions in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120500/vim-settings-file-on-windows#comment37605844_9123701), you may need to run Vim as an administrator to be able to save your changes.

Comment: I did like suhair just said `:e $MYVIMRC`, it works great though a little note should be added for saving... You have to be aware that the config file is protected and in order to write changes to the file, you need to open/run VIM as Administrator. Works great after... Thanks suhair (sorry I can't find how to just add a comment to your post, had to go with an answer, but I sure gave you +1)

Comment: Editing using command:
:e $MYVIMRC
is a good idea, except the file can't be opened for writing. But at least you get the error message showing the file location. In my case this is "C:\Program Files\Vim\\_vimrc". You can add write permission to this file and then make necessary changes.

Answer (score 18):

On Windows systems, the best way to find the value of $HOME is from within Vim, as follows. These commands are useful to see what directories your Vim is using:

```
:version
:echo expand('~')
:echo $HOME
:echo $VIM
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
```

Note the `system vimrc file` and `user vimrc file` paths displayed by the `:version` command. The system vimrc file can be created by an administrator to customize Vim for all users. In addition, each user can have his or her own user `vimrc`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be under `[Your Installation Directory]/Vim/`.

In my case, the `_vimrc` file is under `C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/`. Because `C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim` was the default installation directory when I installed Vim on Windows 10 from the executable installer available at https://www.vim.org/download.php.