# How to create vimrc file or customize vim

Tags: vim

I have been learning basic vim and I found out that you can customize it. I have spent the last hour and a half trying to find out how. I am on windows 10. Apparently, I have to create the vimrc file and add everything myself but I don't even know where to put the file or what kind of file it should be. No tutorial or explanation yet has mentioned where to put the file; they all just say create the file. Some say I should already have the file but I don't. Others give me a command to put into the command prompt but none of those work. Please help, I have no idea why I could not find a solution to such a basic question.

Comment: See the instructions in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9120535/4250161

Comment: is it called _viminfo because I already saw that post and there was no _vimrc in my users folder and neither _vimrc nor _viminfo in my vim forlder.

Comment: You need to check where is $HOME and $VIM points to in your environment and then look for the file there. You can also run ':e $MYVIMRC ' in VIM itself and edit the _vimrc file.

Comment: I checked there and all I found was _viminfo. the :e $MYVIMRC command just creates a new file called $MYVIMRC.

Comment: Go to `c:\Users\<your username>\ ` and make a file, name it `_vimrc`.

Comment: what kind of file?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Now my question seems so dumb.

Comment: https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc